# How can I check RAM/CPU utilization by my database?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, monitoring

I am using postgresql.

I want to monitor RAM usage of My Database server, is there any query or command which given the RAM usage or CPU usage?

Anything regarding MySql will also be helpful.

**EDIT: I want to monitor Database server from Webserver, If usage increases some sort of limit it, webserver will send mails to administrator.**

Comment: What Operating System?

Answer (score 1):

Linux/*nix:

```
top
```

Solaris:

```
prstat
```

Windows:

```
taskmgr.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on a linux/bsd system tool called `top` availabe which will show
you CPU and memory usage of running processes. There are also programs like [mytop](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/mysql/mytop/)
and [mysqlreport](http://hackmysql.com/mysqlreport) which are freely available for download and will show you what your
mysql server is doing.

[Mysql Enterprise Montior](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/monitor.html) can show you actual cpu, memory and various other stats on your mysql instance but sadly it isn't free.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're looking for:

http://theservermonitor.com/pbl_help.php?11/postgres

> The PostgreSQL Module helps you monitor your PostgreSQL Database's performance.
>
> Provides
>
> CPU Usage: The total cpu usage of all the PostgreSQL processes averaged over one minute.
>
> Memory Usage: The total estimated memory usage in percentage of all
>   the PostgreSQL processes. Real memory usage is next to impossible to
>   calculate in a modern OS because of the shared memory pages so our
>   service gives you an estimate based on tipical scenarios.